# Restore access to SSH of own dedicated server with Debian

Tags: ssh, debian

I have own dedicated server. I lost my root login & password for SSH.

All I have now its access to ftp, and access to vhcs panel where I can to create ftp users, mysql...

I collected some info to help you help me:
1. On the server installed Debian, Apache2, Mysql, and PHP5 as user 'www-data'
2. SSH is running.
3. file etc/shadow not exists (only passwd)
4. su, sudo doesn't work when I try run it from PHP
5 Sometime I get errors like "MUst run in terminal"

How can I restore access as root to the server? All I have its access to FTP and PHP with option to run exec & shell_exec

Like this:

```
$result = shell_exec("ls  2>&1");
echo print_r($result);
```

I googled for solution with no luck...

Comment: What do you mean you lost access?  When you try to login via SSH what happens?  Do you get a connection refused, timeout, a login failure, or what?  Go to the server and fix it at the console, or get someone near the console to hook it up through a KVM or something.

Comment: I dont remember what is my root username & password. Usernames I can find in /etc/passwd -  but I haven't password. If I try to connect with SSH to IP with any username from /etc/passwd & password from FTP - it gives me ACCESS DENIED. So I think here no any relation between root password and ftp password, even if it has the same username.

Comment: this question is really "how do I root a server that I have a user account on?" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, ignore anything related to php.  It's completely irrelevant unless you've got the most insecure setup imaginable.

If you can ssh into the system and access sudo from another account, you can try

```
sudo passwd
```

If you can't, you're SOL.  You do not (well, should not) have the permissions via ftp or through php.  You'll have to boot the server using a rescue cd or USB, mount your disk and change the password.

Try a search on google for 'linux lost root password'.  There are thousands of places where this is documented...

Comment: So the only way is to get into data center and physically reset/change password?

Comment: If you have access to a remote console.. no.  If not.. yes.  You can boot to single user without a password unless the system has been set up to require one.